# QAudioDecoder Win7 "no service found" despite VS 2013 installed

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7, multimedia

Installed are:
Win7, 
VS 2013 Community, 
Qt 5.7

Qt does detect the MSVC compiler. The default kit is Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2013 32bit, although it has a warning No debugger set up.

I get the infamous defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.audiodecode"

The same code works just fine on Ubuntu.

What can the problem? I'm desperate.

EDIT: This is a virtual machine (VirtualBox), but I don't think it should make a difference.

Comment: Where does your Qt build come from?

Comment: Hi, I installed the binaries with the Online Installer from the official Qt website.